# How to remove nested keys from a hash list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, nested, key, except

I am now trying for some hours to remove a nested hash key of a hash list.
I saw many solution non-nested hashs wich looks like this:

```
   sample_hash = {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"}
   sample_hash.except("key1")
```

This results in:

```
  {"key2"=>"value2"}
```

But if I try to use the except method on a hash with nested key then it doesn't work.
Here my code:

```
  nested_hash = {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>{
                                           "nested_key1"=>"nestedvalue1",
                                           "nested_key2"=>"nestedvalue2"
                                           }
                }

  nested_hash.except("nested_key2")
```

The except() method returns the nested_hash without any changes. I have looked for a solution how I can pass nested hash-keys to the except method, but couldn't find anything. Is it even possible to pass nested keys to this method or should I use some other method which deletes a nested hash key from my hash list?

Comment: Perhaps you want a real tree, rather than a nested hash. You might look at https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree, https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry, or https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree for gems that might work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what about

```
Hash[nested_hash.map {|k,v| [k,(v.respond_to?(:except)?v.except("nested_key2"):v)] }]

=> {"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>{"nested_key1"=>"nestedvalue1"}}
```

ugh.

Comment: This works great, but could you explain this notation? How is the keyword "Hash" taking in an array index, and why are we mapping each element to an array of [k,v] or [k,v.except("nested_key2")] ?

Comment: see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D , the standard method to create hashes. It accepts either a list of key,value,key,value,... or associations key=>value, key=>value,... or nested array, what we use here.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted solution is valid for the scenario given but if you're looking for something that will do this for arbitrarily nested hash tables then you're going to need a recursive solution. I couldn't find a suitable solution anywhere, so I wrote one [here](https://gist.github.com/steveevers/9d584aed053b9b31467101807462a94c).

Reproduced here with annotations:

```
class Hash
  def except_nested(key)
    r = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(self)) # deep copy the hashtable
    r.except_nested!(key)
  end

  def except_nested!(key)
    self.except!(key)
    self.each do |_, v| # essentially dfs traversal calling except!
      v.except_nested!(key) if v.is_a?(Hash)
    end
  end
end
```

adding it to the `Hash` class so that you can call it the same way you call except/except! anywhere else.

```
t = { a: '1', b: { c: '3', d: '4' } } 

r = t.except_nested(:c) 
# r => {:a=>"1", :b=>{:d=>"4"}}
# t => {:a=>"1", :b=>{:c=>"3", :d=>"4"}}

t.except_nested!(:c)
# t => {:a=>"1", :b=>{:d=>"4"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
my_hash = Hash[nested_hash.map {|k,v| {k=>v.is_a? Array ? v.except("nested_key2") : v}}.map {|key, value| [key, value]}]
```

But this seems wrong, I wish I never started down this path,  I'm willing to bet there is an easier way!

Comment: thx for your suggestion. but it throws a NoMethodError: undefined method `except' for "value1":String

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the nested key will always be there then you can just do

```
nested_hash['key2'].except!('nested_key2')
```

the whole nested_hash will now be lacking 'nested_key2'

Answer (score 0):

For certain edge cases, like arrays and deeply nested hashes, you can use [this gem "except_nested"](https://github.com/abarrak/except_nested) for all scenarios solution:

```rb
h = { name: "Jane", age: 20, preferences: { color: "red", pet: "cat", drink: "coffee" } }

h.except_nested(:age, preferences: [:color, :pet])
=> { name: "Jane", preferences: { drink: "coffee" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash_list = [
  { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' },
  { key1: 'value4', key2: 'value5', key3: 'value6' }
]
keys_to_remove = [:key1, :key3]

# Use map to iterate over each hash and remove the specified keys
new_hash_list = hash_list.map do |hash|
  # Create a new hash based on the original hash
  new_hash = hash.dup

  # Remove the specified keys from the new hash
  keys_to_remove.each { |key| new_hash.delete(key) }

  # Return the modified hash
  new_hash
end

# new_hash_list will now contain hashes with the specified keys removed
puts new_hash_list.inspect
```